# MVC Checkbox returns "false" or ",false"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I'm using the `<li><%= Html.CheckBox("IsPublic", false) %></li>` checkbox. It creates `<input id="IsPublic" name="IsPublic" type="checkbox" value=""><input name="IsPublic" type="hidden" value="false">`.

I can't get it to return a true value. When checked, and submitted to a FromCollection, it's value is ",false" which still gets interpreted as false.

Without the checkbox I can have the Controller method be something like `public JsonResult CreateThing(MyThing thing)` and it correctly places all the fields. Now with the checkbox I'll have to manually set every field from the FormCollection unless I can get the checkbox to be automatically interpreted correctly.

I appreciate assistance.

Comment: Please post your actual MVC render code and the actual rendered markup. Also, if you're using a viewmodel why aren't you using `CheckboxFor`?

Comment: Is `Name` a boolean property? Why have your added `isChecked`?

Comment: Updated with exact code. "IsPublic" is the name of the field. IsChecked, before, was just meant as a stand in for true or false.

Comment: I would read very carefully the documentation on this overload of `Html.Checkbox`.  Specifically, the line "isCheckedType: System.Boolean
true to select the check box; otherwise, false. The value of the check box is retrieved **in this order** - the ModelStateDictionary object, the value of this parameter, the ViewDataDictionary object, and lastly, a checked attribute in the html attributes."  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504981(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: If `IsPublic` is a boolean property in your model, then it's just `Html.CheckBox("IsPublic")` or better `Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsPublic)` In any case your code generates`<input id="IsPublic" name="IsPublic" type="checkbox" value="true">` (not `value=""`) so there is something else going in you code that you haven't shown.

Comment: @erosebe plesase refer the same problem answered here